# ajax form process then page submit after 3-5 seconds

Tags: ajax, forms

```
 $("#sub").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#added_user").attr("action"),
     $("#added_user :input").serializeArray(),
     function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
 });
 clearInput();
 });

<code>$("#added_user").submit( function() {
  return false;
});
</code>
function clearInput() {
    $("#added_user :input").each( function() {
       $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the page to refresh with out going to the insert php page. I want it to show the result div then after 3-5 seconds to refresh the page so you can see what you added.

TIA

Comment: Have you tried location.reload()?